# Windows CE 6.0 Takes Long time to boot

Tags: windows-ce, bsp

I have got VIA BSP from the vendor and i have built a WinCE image using Platform builder. When I am trying to bootup the board with that image, It nearly takes 3 to 5 mins to boot.
Please give me a solution...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 to 5 minutes indicates that there's an issue in the startup sequence.  The most common item I've seen that causes extremely slow booting is that having KITL enabled in the OS build but not attaching from Platform Builder.  What happens in this case is that the OS begins the startup sequence and then waits for a KITL connection for a long time before timing out and continuing the boot process.

That doesn't mean that this is your specific problem - you've not really told us anything to help us help you - this is just a slightly educated guess.  What have you done to debug the issue? What does the debug output from the device look like?  That would probably help you see if there are any failures.  Have you done anything to verify and time driver loading?

Comment: I have solved that issue. I have disabled the KITL and Kernel debugger. Now its working fine... Thank you...

Comment: Then click the greyed out tick mark on the left to mark this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing would be to include less stuff in the image...

Comment: Actually that's not obvious at all.  3-5 minutes has nothing to do with the number of components in the image - even with every component and slow hardware it wouldn't take this long.